Tailwind CSS Grid doesn't seem to be working properly while using Nextjs. Somtimes works with 4 cols, sometimes doesn't
I was working on this project where i had to use grid on a small component.
Main div :-
import Feature from "@/components/Feature";

export default function WebsiteFeatures () {
    return (
        <div className={"grid grid-cols-4"}>
           <div>div</div>
           <div>div</div>
           <div>div</div>
           <div>div</div>
        </div>

    )
}

Parent div :-
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import AboutTitle from "@/components/AboutTitle";
import WebsiteFeatures from "../../public/WebsiteFeatures";

export default function AboutPage () {
    return (
        <div className={"bg-background-grey h-screen w-full"} id={"about"}>
            <Navbar/>
            <AboutTitle/>
            <WebsiteFeatures/>
        </div>
    )
}

Tailwind.config.js :
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {

  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "nav-bar-blue": "#232230",
        "container-blue": "#73AAEB",
        "background-grey": "#1E1E1E"
      },
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        'custom-1': 'repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))',  // Example of a 2-column grid
        'custom-2': 'repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))',  // Example of a 3-column grid
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;

When i try to insert the same code in another component, it works but i doesn't work on this component. Seems to be a problem with a parent div or something, still not able to  figure out.  Sometimes it somehow starts working for a specific numbers of columns (when i try to create a another grid in another component) and then only works for that many columns and no other number of columns.

What do you mean by "not working"? Currently, what is the actual width and height of WebsiteFeatures when inspected in the browser devtools?
